# menu-text does not exists in _settings.scss in Foundation 6.2

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

menu-text does not exists in _settings.scss in Zurb Foudation 6.2. It is actually in foundation.css but I don't want to edit that. Where do I edit menu-text instead?

Answer (score 0):

Add any class to the element and add some css in new custom css file for ex. you have added class `.dummy` to the element

```
.dummy{
    //your css code
}
```

> you can use this css in page also under `<style>` tags but i suggest creating a new `custom.css` file becuase this will be needed throughout the site